# Convert date from unix format to ISO8601

Tags: php, time, unix-timestamp

I'm storing the timestamps as UTC unix epoch time.

I want to convert that time to ISO 8601 format. (`2013-08-01T05:14:48Z`)

For example, unix epoch time of `1375334088` means `Thu, 01 Aug 2013 05:14:48 GMT`.

But when I do `date('c', 1375334088)` it gives `2013-08-01T06:14:48+01:00` instead of `2013-08-01T05:14:48Z`

Comment: May be due to your default time zone settings

Comment: @User016: Yes, thats what I want to know. How to get the ISO 8601 format even if I've set my timezone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', 1375334088);
```

See [`gmdate()`](http://php.net/gmdate).

Answer (score -1):

Should be like:

```
echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', 1375334088);
```